# PrestaShop create new AdminTab

Tags: prestashop

in my file module

```
class Mymodule extends Module
{
   public function install()
   {
      ...
      $this->installModuleTab('AdminMymodule', array(1=>'My Module Admin Tab'), 13)
   }

   private function installModuleTab($tabClass, $tabName, $idTabParent)
   {
      $tab = new Tab();
      $tab->name = $tabName;
      $tab->class_name = $tabClass;
      $tab->module = $this->name;
      $tab->id_parent = $idTabParent;
      $tab->active = 1;
      if(!$tab->save())
        return false;
      return true;
  }
}
```

it working, Admin Tab: 'My Module Admin Tab' has been created. Now, in file AdminMymodule:

```
include_once(PS_ADMIN_DIR.'/../classes/AdminTab.php');

class AdminMymodule extends AdminTab
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function display()
    {
        echo $this->l('This is admin my module tab !');
    }
}
```

when i click to link 'My Module Admin Tab', it result blank page. somebody can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Each tab in prestashop admin tab is a Admin Controller.
You need to put your admin controller file inside your module
like mymodule\controllers\admin\AdminAboutUsController.php
inside the controller you need to put:

```
class AdminAboutUsController extends ModuleAdminController {
   public $asso_type = 'shop';
   public function __construct() {
      $this->module = 'mymodule';
      $this->lang = true;
      $this->context = Context::getContext();
      $this->bootstrap = true;
    parent::__construct();
}

public function initContent()
 {

 }
 }
```

where class name in module creation is

```
   'class_name' => 'AdminAboutUs',
```

Hope this help you to find your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can add a tab in a module like this.
Let us take the module `homeslider` as an example.
First create the controller in `controllers/admin/AdminHomeSliderController.php`
and put this code:

```
<?php

class AdminHomeSliderController extends ModuleAdminController
{
   public function __construct() {

     $token = Tools::getAdminTokenLite('AdminModules');
     $currentIndex='index.php?       controller=AdminModules&token='.$token.'&configure=homeslider&tab_module=front_office_features&module_name=homeslider';

     parent::__construct();
     Tools::redirectAdmin($currentIndex);
  }
}
```

and in the module's file, `homeslider.php`,
add these two functions:

```
private function createInnovativesLabsTabs() {
  $langs = Language::getLanguages();
  $id_lang = (int)Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT');
  $ndiaga_tab = new Tab();
  $ndiaga_tab->class_name = 'AdminHomeSlider';
  $ndiaga_tab->module = 'homeslider';
  $ndiaga_tab->id_parent = 0;
  foreach($langs as $l){
    $ndiaga_tab->name[$l['id_lang']] = $this->l('HomeSlider');
  }
  $ndiaga_tab->save();
  $tab_id = $ndiaga_tab->id;
  @copy(dirname(__FILE__).'/AdminHomeSlider.gif',_PS_ROOT_DIR_.'/img/t/AdminHomeSlider.gif'); 
  Configuration::updateValue('HOME_SLIDER_TAB_ID',$tab_id);             
  return true;
}

public function deleteInnovativesLabsTabs(){    
  $tab = new Tab(Configuration::get('HOME_SLIDER_TAB_ID'));   

  $tab->delete();
  Configuration::deleteByName('HOME_SLIDER_TAB_ID');    

  return true;
}
```

You will need to call them during install and uninstall this way:

```
 //install
 $this->createInnovativesLabsTabs();

 //uninstall
 $this->deleteInnovativesLabsTabs();
```

Answer (score -1):

You must create a back office controller. In your module's folder this would be the structure

```
controllers/admin/AdminModuleName.php
```

This file class must be named like

```
class AdminmodulenameController extends ModuleAdminController.
```

You can choose to add it when installing the module, or youy can add it manually from the admin menu. You can find an extended explanation in the prestashop docs ([Creating a PrestaShop module](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS14/Creating+a+PrestaShop+module#CreatingaPrestaShopmodule-Creatingthemodule))